# How to rename the layers in 2D animation

Tags: 2d, layers

I want to have an organized layer by changing the names, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 2):

You can double click on Layers name, either in layers panel, GP dopesheet window or even outliner.

[image]

Comment: Or press F2 with the name hilighted.